# how convert a .cmd into a PowerShell script?

Tags: powershell, batch-file, branch

I have the next file (.cmd):

```
@echo off
setlocal

for /f %%b in (Branches.txt) do (
    set branches=%%b
)

call :parse "%branches%"

goto :eos

:parse

set branches=%1
set branches=%branches:"=%

for /f "tokens=1* delims=," %%a IN ("%branches%") DO (
  if not "%%a" == "" call :sub %%a
  if not "%%b" == "" call :parse "%%b"
)

goto :eos

:sub

echo Starting compilation for branch :[%1]

goto :eos

:eos
endlocal
```

Where "Branches.txt" contains this:

```
branch1,branche2,branche3,...,branchn
```

The script grabs the last line from Branches.txt, removes any quotes in the string, and splits the line on commas. If there is at least one element, it calls sub with the first element, and if the line has two or more elements when it is split, it re-parses the string with the first element removed.

I need this code but in a PowerShell .ps1 file

Comment: Can you at least explain what this batch is doing. For this question to have staying power it needs to attempt to be useful to the community. I'm a gifted amateur with PowerShell but i'm not going to learn batch to try and help

Comment: @Matt - the script grabs the last line from Branches.txt, removes any quotes in the string, and splits the line on commas. If there is at least one element, it calls sub with the first element, and if the line has two or more elements when it is split, it re-parses the string with the first element removed.

Comment: @SomethingDark - Exactly!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is the start of what you will be looking for. Consider the following content of the txt file branches.txt. I have quoted the last line to show that they are being removed as part of the process.

```
branch1,branche2,branche3
branch2,branche2,branche3
"branch3","branche2",branche3"
```

**Code Snippet**

```
$path = "c:\temp\braches.txt"
$lastLine = Get-Content -Path $path | Select-Object -Last 1
$lastLine -replace '"' -split "," | ForEach-Object{
    Write-Host "Do something with: $_"
}
```

will produce the following console output.

```
Do something with: branch3
Do something with: branche2
Do something with: branche3
```

This will take the file and read its contents as a string array. We take the last line and remove the quotes using a `-replace`. Then using `-split` we create another array. Each element of that array can then be processed individually.